# Does Azure support have access to all resources and sensitive data like KeyVault?

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-keyvault

I cannot find any documentation on how Azure support staff members or for that matter any other Azure staff members (Administrators,Security Experts, whatever they have) get access to client resources. What i am trying to say is if you have sensitive data for example in KeyVault can it be viewed by Microsoft in any way? 
For example they add themselves as global administrator or even have some higher roles in the background? Or can they just decrypt all data in KeyVault as they have all the keys?

P.S. I am talking purely theoretically.

Comment: I am kind of curious why you ask this. Is it about decision making whether data in the cloud is more/less secure than data in your own (on-premises) datacenter?

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/fundamentals/protection-customer-data):

> Access to customer data by Microsoft operations and support personnel is denied by default. When access to customer data is granted, leadership approval is required and then access is carefully managed and logged. The access-control requirements are established by the following Azure Security Policy:
>
> - No access to customer data, by default.
> - No user or administrator accounts on customer virtual machines (VMs).
> - Grant the least privilege that's required to complete task; audit and log access requests.
>
> Azure support personnel are assigned unique corporate Active Directory accounts by Microsoft. Azure relies on Microsoft corporate Active Directory, managed by Microsoft Information Technology (MSIT), to control access to key information systems. Multi-factor authentication is required, and access is granted only from secure consoles.
>
> All access attempts are monitored and can be displayed via a basic set of reports.

Please, take a look at the [Trust Center](https://www.microsoft.com/en/trust-center/privacy/data-access?market=af) as well.

Comment: Thank you. So at the end they have access if they so choose.

Comment: *if they so choose* that sounds like they do it all the time, but there a strict rules. Yes, they can. But it is safe to assume they won't unless they've asked you (for problem solving/diagnostics) or it is a legal thing. Otherwise there wouldn't be a single organisation putting their data in the hands of MS. Anyway, access it logged. You can also [bring your own key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/information-protection/byok-price-restrictions)

Comment: yes i agree it is not happening at all, but i presume if they get legally pressed they might do it. [cloud act](https://www.devoteam.com/newsroom/cloud-act-new-measures-companies-european-personal-data/)